CompleteMultipartUploadCommand always return error R2 cloudflare
I try to use multipart upload. I already set CORS of the bucket. And do all step based on this Multipart uploads to Cloudlfare R2 + Workers
Upload init with reponse below
{"msg":"Success: /getMultiPartUpload","response":{"$metadata": 
{"httpStatusCode":200,"attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0},"AbortDate":"2024-09- 
05T21:01:52.000Z","AbortRuleId":"Default%20Multipart%20Abort%20Rule","Bucket":"haluv-post- 
video","Key":"bucket-name","UploadId":"AFeJAbAoJRPjhzMYM}}

Upload part with reponse below
..."ETag":"\"dfbf2996205d747c40ab5cc43a94300e\""}}
..."ETag":"\"ff3b8f9d875e5f0bced05c50bb9181ab\""}}
..."ETag":"\"a0f1e95938135f7118e32e8a44820813\""}}
..."ETag":"\"e0e174e3ba4157de8d66b080d7a09d41\""}}

Step one and two are work, but when i do Upload complete, it return 500 error code
async function completeMultipartUpload(S3, request, headers) {

try {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const params = url.searchParams;
    const bucket = params.get('bucket');
    const key = params.get('key');
    const uploadId = params.get('uploadId');

    const partsData = await request.json();
    const parts = partsData.parts;

    const input = {
        "Bucket": bucket,
        "Key": key,
        "MultipartUpload": {
            "Parts": parts
        },
        "UploadId": uploadId
    }

    const command = new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand(input); // IN HERE THE ERROR OCCUR
    const response = await S3.send(command);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
        msg: '/completeMultipartUpload',
        response: response
    }), {
        status: 200,
        headers: headers
    });
} catch (err) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
        msg: 'Error: /completeMultipartUpload',
        error: JSON.stringify(err)
    }), {
        status: 500,
        headers: headers
    });
}

Error
DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 500 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.

What is the text of the error message?

I can't track it. from debug just show 500 and blablabla
